# Code for creating icons

Tags: wpf, xaml

This question is probably stupid but I have googled for some time now and didn't find any answers.
I found a post about button styles in where someone added this code example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#373737" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="PathIcon" Width="15" Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#4C87B3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,0,0,0" Data="F1 M 30.0833,22.1667L 50.6665,37.6043L 50.6665,38.7918L 30.0833,53.8333L 30.0833,22.1667 Z "/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />                                
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter TargetName="PathIcon" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

This creates a button with an arrow on the left side of the button.

My question is: How is this data called?

`Data="F1 M 30.0833,22.1667L 50.6665,37.6043L 50.6665,38.7918L 30.0833,53.8333L 30.0833,22.1667 Z "`

EDIT:

I tried to export some icons. Sometimes I get usable Path.Data and sometimes I get something like this:

```
    <!-- Created with Ai->XAML Export Plug-In Version 0.2 (PC/64) -->
<!-- By Mike Swanson (http://blog.mikeswanson.com/)           -->

    <Viewbox Width="111.000" Height="81.000"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas Width="111.000" Height="81.000">
    </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```

Can I even use this and how?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path.data

Comment: And you can pull the xaml (path data) from the material design site for a large number of different icons. https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: Beautiful. I was also trying to put images from photoshop to xaml with some success. Might find something usefull here, thanks.

Comment: you can use Syncfusion's MetroStudio also.